# Book about kid with unhealthy father realtionship

Tags: identification-request

I read a book before a long time ago about a kid (named axel, axis something like that) who was a brilliant young kid attending a school with older people. I don't remember much, except that he crossdressed as a disguise with a wig and even used toilet paper to mimic the female genitalia. Eventually he found out his father was someone he knew (a dean or sort) and was evil?

EDIT: Book was in english, I belive it was more on the "adult" side of a story, though I am not sure. If I remember right the book cover looked dark, with gray and black colors.